# How to back update Postgres database inside K8s cluster

Tags: postgresql

I have setup a postgres database inside the Kubernetes cluster and now I would like to backup the database and don't know how it is possible.
Can anyone help me to get it done ?

Thanks

Comment: How to backup a PostgreSQL instance is unrelated to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can backup your database. You can setup a CronJob to periodically run `pg_dump` and upload the dumped data into a cloud bucket. Check [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-kubernetes-cron-job-backup-postgres-db-prakarsh-/) blog post for more details.

However, I recommend you to use a Kubernetes native disaster recovery tool like [Velero](https://velero.io/), [Stash](https://stash.run/docs/v2021.06.23/addons/postgres/standalone/), [Portworx PX-Backup](https://portworx.com/products/px-backup/), etc.

If you use an operator to manage your database such as [zalando/postgres-operator](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator), [CrunchyData](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/schedule-postgresql-backups-and-retention-with-kubernetes), [KubeDB](https://kubedb.com/), etc. You can use their native database backup functionality.

**Disclosure:** I am one of the developer of [Stash](https://stash.run/) tool.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I forgot to mention that my cluster is setup in GCP. Does it make any difference than the link you sent ?

Comment: Yes. In case, of GCP, you might want to use Google Cloud Storage to store your backed up data. In this case, you can use [this gcs specific image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nullriver/postgres-docker-gcs-backup) to create your cronjob.

Comment: If you use  Stash for backup, then the link I have provided for Stash in second paragraph already uses GCS as example for data storage.

Comment: great, thank you sir. I will try them both, however I have never done this and might make mistakes :D

Comment: We learn through mistakes. So, feel free to break to learn. :P

Answer (score -1):

you can run this command to export the postgres sql file inside your Kubernetes cluster.

```
kubectl exec [pod-name] -- bash -c "pg_dump -U [postgres-user] [database-name]" > database.sql
```